# How to time a program ignoring time spend waiting for other threads

Tags: java, multithreading, timing

Suppose I have the following programs:

```
public class ProgramA {
  public void doSomething(ProgramC c) {
    c.doSomething();
    // Do something else that takes 5 seconds.
  }
}

public class ProgramB {
  public void doSomething(ProgramC c) {
    c.doSomething();
    // Do something else that takes 2 seconds.
  }
}

public class ProgramC {
  public synchronized void doSomething() {
    // Do something that takes 10 seconds
  }
}
```

I want to time program A and program B to find out how long they take (using Guava's stopwatch or similar). When run in serial, I get 15s and 12s as expected. 
However, when run in parallel I get e.g. 15s and 22s as program B spends time waiting for the lock on program C.

Is there a way to disregard time spend blocked in this way and get the same timings as when run in serial? Even more helpful would be a breakdown e.g. "Program B took 22s, of which 10s was blocking on other threads"

Comment: So what you want is to get statistics on the various states your threads are in like how often your threads are blocked or not running?

Comment: What I really want is to know when a program has got slower for reasons that are unrelated to threading, e.g. if program A starts taking 25s rather than 15s I would like to know that the extra 10s comes from thread contention rather than a performance regression somewhere else in the program.

Comment: You can profile your application as well as look at thread states with visualvm.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to monitor this at the thread level, you could call [`getState()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getState())the `Thread` object, to see how long each `Thread` has the `BLOCKED` `state`, compared to the `RUNNABLE` state.